# Nodejs brute force attack mitigation not based on public IP address?

Tags: node.js

I was using the nodejs express-bouncer npm package which attempts to mitigate brute-force attacks. It works by increasing the delay with each failed request using a Fibonacci formula. This package is very easy to integrate and use. However, one issue that I have with this package is that it blocks the request based on public IP address. When looking at the code of the package, I can see that the IP address is collected like this:

```
var address; try { address =
            req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress ||
            req.socket.remoteAddress || req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
        } catch (error) { }
```

This returns a public IP address. The reason I do not want to block based on just public IP adress is because I do not want one user sharing a common network accidently entering to many incorrect user/password combination and blocking everyone within the network from logging in. I am pretty sure that that is not what Facebook or Amazon does but I am not sure how they handle this situation.

Can I block request based  on combination of both public and private IP address?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of whether you can block requests based on a combination of public and private IP addresses:

No. Unless you are in the same network as the client and they send requests to your server via the local network instead of the internet, you have no way to get the private IP address because nobody outside of the client's network knows about it.

If the client connects to your app using the private address of your server from the same network, then the IP-address of the client will be their private address and you can block using that - and already would do that with your current code, as far as I can tell.